# **Complete Beginner** Why doesnt my Javascript load?

Tags: javascript

I just started learning javascript today after learning html and css.

Somehow the Script doesnt show on my site.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="c01.css">
</head>
<body>
    <script src="addContent.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and the addContent.js script

```
var today = new Date();
var hourNow = new today.getHours();
var greeting;

    if (hourNow > 18) {
        greeting='Good evening!';
    } else if (hourNow > 12) {
        greeting='Good afternoon!';
    } else if (hourNow > 0) {
        greeting='Good Morning!';
    } else {
        greeting ='Welcome!';
    }

document.write('<h1>' + greeting + '</h1>');
```

I Feel like the answer to my problem is fairly easy but i can't find the Problem please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What directory has your script?

Comment: Depending on how quickly the javascript is executed, it may well put the greeting html after the closing </html> tag, hiding it from view. Insert a div or span with an id tag, then insert the html using the findelementbyid function.

Comment: @stark Ally my files are in the same directory.

Comment: There should be an error in the console of your browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to remove the word `new` from the line

```
var hourNow = new today.getHours();
```

Here's a working example

```js
var today = new Date();
var hourNow = today.getHours();
var greeting;

    if (hourNow > 18) {
        greeting='Good evening!';
    } else if (hourNow > 12) {
        greeting='Good afternoon!';
    } else if (hourNow > 0) {
        greeting='Good Morning!';
    } else {
        greeting ='Welcome!';
    }

document.write('<h1>' + greeting + '</h1>');
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="c01.css">
</head>
<body>
    <script src="addContent.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: thank you very very much. I think i need to take a break.... I should have seen this.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, look:

```
var today = new Date(); // new is the root of you date.
```

then when you root new is already defined, u don't have use again:

```
var hourNow = new today.getHours();
```

This is the right code:

```
var hourNow = today.getHours(); // Use this code.
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the new from var hourNow = new today.getHours()

```js
var today = new Date();
var hourNow = today.getHours();
var greeting;

    if (hourNow > 18) {
        greeting='Good evening!';
    } else if (hourNow > 12) {
        greeting='Good afternoon!';
    } else if (hourNow > 0) {
        greeting='Good Morning!';
    } else {
        greeting ='Welcome!';
    }

document.write('<h1>' + greeting + '</h1>');
```